# Same shortcuts across input sources

Tags: macos, keyboard

OS X by default supports emacs key bindings, for example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to go to the beginning of the line, My problem is when I switch to a different language these <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key bindings stop working.

Is it possible to either modify the keyboard layout to send English letters when the key is pressed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>. Or add new binding to OS X that accept the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> binding with the correspoding letters in the other input source. Or is there a third choice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried modifying some non-Latin layouts that came with [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/ukelele), but couldn't get shortcuts like <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to work with them. I haven't found a way to get them to work with my custom keyboard layout either, but I'm probably just missing something...

Another option would be to create ~/Library/KeyBindings/ save a property list like this as DefaultKeyBinding.dict:

```
{
    "^ф" = moveToBeginningOfParagraph:; // ctrl-a on the Russian layout
    "^щ" = (insertNewlineIgnoringFieldEditor:, moveBackward:); // ctrl-o on the Russian layout
    // ...
}
```

Some of the default control key actions, copied from [lri.me/keybindings](http://lri.me/keybindings):

```
"^p" = moveUp:;
"^n" = moveDown:;
"^b" = moveBackward:;
"^f" = moveForward:;
"^h" = deleteBackward:;
"^d" = deleteForward:;
"^a" = moveToBeginningOfParagraph:;
"^e" = moveToEndOfParagraph:;
"^k" = deleteToEndOfParagraph:;
"^l" = centerSelectionInVisibleArea:;
"^v" = pageDown:;
"^t" = transpose:;
"^y" = yank:;
"^o" = (insertNewlineIgnoringFieldEditor:, moveBackward:);
"^P" = moveUpAndModifySelection:;
"^N" = moveDownAndModifySelection:;
"^B" = moveBackwardAndModifySelection:;
"^F" = moveForwardAndModifySelection:;
"^A" = moveToBeginningOfParagraphAndModifySelection:;
"^E" = moveToEndOfParagraphAndModifySelection:;
"^V" = pageDownAndModifySelection:;
"~^b" = moveWordBackward:;
"~^f" = moveWordForward:;
"~^B" = moveWordBackwardAndModifySelection:;
"~^F" = moveWordForwardAndModifySelection:;
```